# compilation error C++ templated function with iterators as arugments

Tags: c++, templates

I thought I was starting to get the hang of C++ ....

Then I wrote what I thought we are very simple templated function and all of a sudden it seems like nothing makes sense again. The compiler doesn't even seem to like the fact that I have defined a templated function, which seems a bit crazy. It is single unit of compilation so I am not sure what it would be complaining about.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<int> int_vec_type;

template <typename Type>
bool print_vec(Type::const_iterator itr, const Type::const_iterator end)
{
    for (; itr != end; ++itr) {
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    }

    return true;
}

int
main()
{
    int_vec_type ivec;

    ivec.push_back(0);
    ivec.push_back(1);
    ivec.push_back(2);

    print_vec(ivec.begin(), ivec.end());

    return 0;
}
```

these are the compilation errors:

tia.cc:7:22: error: template declaration of ‘bool print_vec’

tia.cc:7:37: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘itr’

tia.cc:7:42: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’

tia.cc: In function ‘int main()’:

tia.cc:25:39: error: ‘print_vec’ was not declared in this scope

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords, but your function arguments don't match your function logic.

Comment: @chris: That linked question, how is it related to this question?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, It [*does* work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9c7121b1135a6af838faadd7f6ea491c) with it in there and some help with the template argument, but of course taking the iterator as the template parameter is the proper solution. Either way, I thought the link would help the OP, at least when the situation inevitably arises and creates another dupe.

Comment: @chris: That definition of *does work* is interesting... basically you are saying that if you explicitly name the type, then the compiler has no problem deducing it. Yes, that is correct. (As a side note, why do people like 'liveworkspace' so much? In both Safari and IE the fonts are painful to read when pretty-printing is enabled)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Yeah, it's not much of a solution compared to the best one, but I meant the OP's method can work if you do it the right way. About LWS (compared to Ideone, at least), I like it because a) The compiler is much more recent, b) The tabs only do three spaces instead of eight, c) I think there are more useful warnings turned on, and d) It lets me edit the code straight after compiling instead of going back, or copy-pasting if someone else posts a link. I suppose having boost is nice as well. I wasn't aware of the font issue; I've only ever used it with chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the container is not deducible from the type of the iterator. You can simply transform the template into:

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool print_vec(Iterator itr, const Iterator end)
{
    for (; itr != end; ++itr) {
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First problem: You have not used `typename`. Wherever a type depends on a template argument, you must prefix the type with `typename`.

Secondly, the compiler cannot infer `type`. It can only see the type of `ivec.begin()` and has no idea about any other types that might have it as a typedef. You can only take the `const_iterator` directly- you can't take a `T::const_iterator`- without passing `T` explicitly, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to template in terms of iterator types, since the container's type cannot be deduced from the function arguments:

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool print_vec(Iterator itr, Iterator end) { .... }
```